# Converting one column into multiple column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with table1

[table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9Wsb.jpg)

Output should be in this format
[table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfIEj.jpg)subject per students can change

Comment: PIVOT not supported by MySQL. Create SP with dynamic SQL.

Comment: did you try something

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work, but with different no of comma separated values I am not sure how to do

```
SELECT Column1,
  substr(Column2, 1, length(Column2) - length(substring_index(Column2, ',', -2))) Column2,
  substring_index(substring_index(Column2, ',', -2), ',', 1) Column3,
  substr(trim(substring_index(Column2, ',', -1)),1,2) Column4,
  substring_index(Column2, ' ', -1) Column5
FROM table
```